# get least row weight item or top row of draggable views

Tags: views

I have a requirement in my project adding draggable feature using custom module and i have impemented it but the problem is getting least row weight item after user has reordered the item ie top item of the view.
Please provide me the solution for this.
Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more detail and/or clarify exactly what it is you wish to accomplish in order for anyone to come up with a good solution...

Comment: Hi jerdiggity,thanks for ur quick reply.I have written a custom module for drag and drop functionality using tabledrag (drupal_add_tabledrag()).Now my problem is when user reorders the view items using drag and drop and saves those changes I need to get the first or top row of the view items.Basically top row will have least row weight right?.finally i need to get the top row of the draggableview based on row weights or anything if possible.Thanks,Awaiting ur reply.